# Can backlinks from question and answer sites such as StackExchange and Quora, help a blog's SEO?

Tags: backlinks, blog

If I put my blog URL on a question and answer site, like Quora or StackExchange, will it help in my site's SEO and will I get better rankings in search engines?

Comment: Don't spam sites just to get backlinks. Additionally, stack overflow for sure, and probably quora as well, nofollow external links so they have no SEO value.

Comment: I have a couple of links here written honestly. I did not do it for rank or any other reason except to help users which is good because there is no value passed. I barely get any traffic from the links either. So as a strategy, I suggest something else. Do not to ride on the back of others work. You want organic links. Let them come to you.

Comment: The moderators here typically remove links that appear spammy.    We tend to edit out almost all links from new users.    We discourage "link only" posts where people have to click to some other page to get their answer.   Links are good when they are for reference and documentation.   They are not good when they are created to promote your site.    Spamming StackExchange with links to your site will get you banned.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller see [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/20534/4107), it's definitely a spammer.

Comment: Despite that this question came from a spammer, this question itself is not spam.

Answer (score 2):

> ...can I get higher rank in search engines ?

Your method of trying to get ranks might be impossible. First of all, you're asking for a 3rd party (aka stackexchange) to transfer a large amount of guest traffic from search engines to your site via their service, and secondly, with the right programming skills, people can make their websites set up so that any external link on the page can be "nofollow"-ed. which means search engines wouldn't even try to access them.

What you need to do is write quality content (a.k.a. intelligible text that people actually want to read), create sitemaps, send the sitemaps to search engines via their interfaces (for example, submit one to the Google Search Console when you login to it and register your domain), then shortly after, you should notice guests visiting your pages.

Without the quality content, there is no point on wasting your time trying to get people for no effort.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.
If we look at this from a seo perspective you could get higher rankings if you do it right.

- Your link must be a Follow link. Nofollow links won't work.
- You need to figure out how to make your link relevant and valid. If you do it the wrong way i.e. use money keywords (stuffing) in your anchor text, you might end up with a penalty instead.
- If you add value with your comment and/or post i.e. help solve an issue and your link looks legit you can use this without worrying.

However, don't expect any miracles from this. It is usually low quality links.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is yes, but not in a direct “link for better rankings” exchange.

Instead, Quora can be a great resource for SEOs looking to:

- Determine priority and popularity of common questions asked by potential prospects and customers.
- Find influencers and network with them for high quality, “white hat” link opportunities.
- Build up a repository of nofollow links with referral traffic potential.
- Barnacle your brand to top ranking pages in over 5.8 million Google SERPs.